# Proj4Leaflet transform from 23700 to 4326 in Leaflet

Tags: c#, leaflet

I want to yous Leaflet with EPSG:23700 but Map is alway grey.

```
  if (!elem.map) {

            var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:23700',
                '+proj=somerc +lat_0=47.14439372222222 +lon_0=19.04857177777778 +x_0=650000 +y_0=200000 +ellps=GRS67 +datum=HD72 +towgs84=57.01,-69.97,-9.29 +units=m +no_defs',
                {
                    resolutions: [
                        8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128
                    ],
                    origin: [0, 0]
                });
            elem.map = L.map(elementId, { crs: crs, attributionControl: false });

            L.tileLayer(tileUrl, {
                maxZoom: crs.options.resolutions.length,
                minZoom: 0,
                continuousWorld: true,
                attribution: 'Map data © <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap contributors</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://www.kartena.se/">Kartena</a>'
            }).addTo(elem.map);        
        }
```

I do not understand why it does not work, please.

Comment: What's the value of `tileUrl`? I also don't se any reference to data in EPSG:4326 in your code there.

Comment: You are right. I have added it but it still shows gray map.